# IPhone app Memory Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, instruments

I check my Iphone App in Instruments and it's using 392.00kb of memory which does not decrease  and keeps on increasing.

So although I am not using a `UITableView` there is an entry for `[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using HeapShot, see this [tutorial](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/#more-1949) by bbum.

Basically in the Allocations instrument click Heapshot, run an iteration of your app, repeat 3 or four times and look for items that are persisting.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick check is Analyze. Just run Analyze and it may find places where you are not handling memory correctly.